# Regex group may not exist

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using regex in C# to extract parts of a URL, but if the URL doesn't have "www" then it changes the grouping count so I can't always go to `match.Groups[3].Value` to get my value. My regex is

```
 Regex r1 = new Regex(@"(http[s]?://)([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)(\.([A-Za-z0-9\-]+))*");
```

Can you make group 2 always exist so it doesn't break the count?

Comment: You should probably be using the [`Uri` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) if possible.

Comment: within the URI Class or or even a string class.. perhaps you can implement the `Split()` method

Comment: Not sure if split will do it on the dot as if "www." doesnt exist then that dot wont either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an optional passive (non-capturing) group (ie: '(?:www.)?' below):

`Regex r1 = new Regex(@"(http[s]?://)(?:www\.)?([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)(\.([A-Za-z0-9\-]+))*");`

The existence (or not) of 'www.' will then not factor into the grouping count.

Comment: Thanks this worked :) . I did try the named grouping which kind of worked but meant I had to check if existed every time first.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, should read the question more closely before answering it. :)

If you name the groups, then you should be able to index them by name and check the "Success" property for each to see what elements were actually matched.

Of course, for some regex the whole thing won't match at all unless all of the capture groups had a match. It depends on the regex.